# Facebook synchronisation with php - get facebook data

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have problem with authorization of my facebook application. When I run my application normally on my local web server process goes like this:

```
**Get facebook user->If user is not logged on -> Redirect user on facebook login page**

**Get facebook user->If user is  logged on -> Redirect user to authorize my facebook application->everything goes right without problems**
```

When I host my application on facebook using iframe, second process is not working (user never get show the authorization window), and I get following exception:

```
Error validating access token: User xxxxxxx has not authorized application xxxxxxx.
```

I'm using CodeIgniter PHP framework, and this is my PHP code:

```
$this->load->library('facebook');
        $user = null;
        $user_profile = null;

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) {
          try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
            $user_profile = $this->facebook->api($user);

          } 
          catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            show_error(print_r($e, TRUE), 500);
          }
        }
        else{
            $data = array(
            'redirect_uri' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','scope'=>'email');
            $access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
        redirect($this->facebook->getLoginUrl($data));

        }
        $data['facebook']=$user_profile;
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/prijavaKlasicnoFacebook', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not load the OAuth dialog in an iframe – security reasons.

You have to load it into the top-most window instance – so no server-side redirect, but a client-side “redirect” using `top.location.href = "…";`

Get your script to output this JS snippet (including the correct login URL) inside an otherwise empty document.

Comment: I don't understand what I need to do?

Comment: Again: __not__ a server-side redirect, because with that you stay in the iframe – you need to “break out” of it, and that can only be done client-side with JS. So generate the appropriate JS code, and deliver it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should also provide "Read Stream" and "Publish Data" in your scope.